# <nav> element moves out of parent when having <a> element as a child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I was modifying HTML to make drop down panels in order to minimize use of JavaScript.

```css
.nav-link {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.panel-link {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
.nav-link:hover .panel-link {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <a href="withoutchild.html" class="nav-link">
     <span>Without Child</span>
     <nav class="panel-link">
        <h1>Works</h1>
     </nav>
  </a>
  <a href="withchild.html" class="nav-link">
     <span>With Child</span>
     <nav class="panel-link">
        <a>Not Works</a>
     </nav>
  </a>
</nav>
```

When you hover both of them, you notice that only the first link opens its drop down panel when you hover it. However, with the second link (Which was layed out exactly the same), it did not because it had a link element as the child. When I view the inspector of Chrome, I realized the '.panel-link' element moved out of the '.nav-link' element, and is now a sibling of '.nav-link'. which looked just like this:

```html
<nav class="nav">
    <a href="withoutchild.html" class="nav-link">
       <span>Without Child</span>
       <nav class="panel-link">
          <h1>Works</h1>
       </nav>
    </a>
    <a href="withchild.html" class="nav-link">
       <span>With Child</span>
    </a>
    
    <!-- This element is moved outside its parent -->
    <nav class="panel-link">
          <a>Not Works</a>
    </nav>
 </nav>
```

Comment: Ugh position: absolute; would be needed to overlay other elements. Even when the top is specified, it would still not work. I just tried with absolute positioning and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested `<a>` (anchor tags) are illegal and result in unrecoverable errors.

In plain English, browsers ignore all contents of the nested `<a>`, until they meet the end of this tag (`</a>`), which they use to close the parent `<a>` tag.

Use the HTML validator of your choice for more details. I use [nu](https://html5.validator.nu/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you have an `<a>` tag within a parent `<a>` tag.

I'm not sure what you wanted the `<h1>` text/link to look like so kept it in anyway. Using CSS, hovering a div can reveal another div.

```css
.panel-link {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-link {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-link-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-link-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  display: block;
}

.nav-link-content a:hover {
  background-color: #fff000
}

.nav-link:hover .nav-link-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="nav-link">
    <a href="withoutchild.html" class="panel-link"><span>Without Child</span></a>
    <div class="nav-link-content">
      <h1>Works</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-link">
    <a href="withchild.html" class="panel-link"><span>With Child</span></a>
    <div class="nav-link-content">
      <a href="child1.html">Child 1</a>
      <a href="child2.html">Child 2</a>
      <a href="child3.html">Child 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```